# Javascript setInterval change background?

Tags: javascript, flash, setinterval

I want to use javascript to make an element change it's background color to red when it is jumped to from a link further up the page. Then after a second it should change back to white, to give a sort of flashing effect.
I've managed to get it to change to red then back to white, only it keeps on going! Can anyone tell me how to make it flash just once?

This is my javascript code...

```
 function glow() {
        setInterval( function() {

        var see = document.getElementById("see");
        var run = document.getElementById("run");
        var enter = document.getElementById("enter");

            see.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; 
            run.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            enter.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            }, 400);

        setInterval( function() {
        var see = document.getElementById("see");
        var run = document.getElementById("run");
        var enter = document.getElementById("enter");

                see.style.backgroundColor = 'white'; 
                run.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
                enter.style.backgroundColor = 'white'; 
                } , 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change setInterval to setTimeout to only do it once.